# 2 Point Perspective - How to find 2nd Vanishing Point for a Flat Wall

Tags: geometry

Scenario:

- I am given a Photograph of a wall.
- Assume the wall's thickness is negligible.
- The wall's side are parallel to one another (both physically and diagrammatically).
- The wall's top and bottom are parallel to one another (physically speaking), however will appear slanted on the diagram as it is seen from an angle.
- The wall appears at an angle so that one vanishing point can be made from the bottom and top of the walls.
- The wall's height is 'h' and the wall's length is 'l'

[image: See here for the Diagram]

Question:

Is there a way to correctly locate the second Vanishing Point such that it (the second vanishing point) is physically perpendicular to the 2 sides of the wall? If so, how is it done?

Additional Question:
Do we need to know any additional information in regards to the camera's configuration/position?

Answer (score 1):

In your drawing there is nothing for which you would use the second vanishing point.
If the wall's thickness were not negligible, you could use a second vanishing point to determine how much smaller the far side of the wall should appear
compared to the near side of the wall.

Another possible use for a second vanishing point is to make the
sides of the walls taper toward each other, as if you were viewing the wall
from a higher (or lower) vantage point.
That vanishing point would be far above or below the wall.

The vanishing points (there are up to three of them) represent
the directions of the axes of a coordinate system centered at the
viewer's location.
For example, one vanishing point could be due north, one due east,
and one straight up from where you are standing.
(This could occur if the wall were oriented either north-south or east-west.)
The human eye can take in such widely separated objects all at once,
but when we look at a picture we usually use only a small part of our
visual field.
Putting more than one vanishing point within the frame of the picture
(or even close to the frame of the picture) gives you a panoramic effect.